# What is wrong with this proof that $\sin’x=0$?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives

I was writing out the proof of $\sin’x=\cos x$ and ended up with something that was wrong, but I’m not sure why.  Here it is:
[image]

Comment: For a general $x$, for instance for $x=\pi/4$, $$\frac{\sin x}h$$ has no limit for $h\to 0$, so the first split makes no sense.

Comment: How you jumped from 3rd line to 4th? you will have a term of $\cos{x}$, as, $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sin{h}}{h}=1$

Comment: So $\infty-\infty=0?\ \ddot\frown$

Comment: Instead of splitting the fractions the way you did, try $$\frac{\sin(x)(\cos(h) - 1)}{h} + \frac{\sin(h)\cos(x)}{h}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You broke up the initial limit incorrectly. The correct proof would be like this. (Notice how the limit is split up.)
$$\sin’x = \lim_{h\to 0}\big(\frac{\sin(x+h)-sin(x)}{h}\big)$$
$$=\lim_{h\to 0}\big(\frac{\sin x\cos h+\cos x\sin h-\sin x}{h}\big)$$
$$=\lim_{h\to 0}\big(\frac{\sin x\cos h- \sin x+\cos x\sin h}{h}\big)$$
$$=\lim_{h\to 0}\big(\frac{\sin x(\cos h-1)+\cos x\sin h}{h}\big)$$
$$=\lim_{h\to 0}\big(\frac{\sin x(\cos h-1)}{h}+\frac{\cos x\sin h}{h}\big)$$
$$=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sin x(\cos h-1)}{h}+\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\cos x\sin h}{h}$$
$$=\sin x\cdot\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\cos h-1}{h}+\cos x\cdot\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sin h}{h}$$
$$=\sin x\cdot 0 + \cos x\cdot 1 = \cos x$$
$$\implies \boxed{\sin’x = \cos x}$$

Answer (score 6):

In the second to last line, both limits don't exist. Akin to $\infty-\infty \neq 0$

Answer (score 0):

You have no reason to simplify

$$\frac{\sin x\cos h+\cos x\sin h}{h}$$ in $$\frac{\sin x}h.$$